# D3.js tree layout - Want to get count of descendant

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'd like to know how could I get the count of descendant of node.

I can get the count of children using this code.

```
console.log(d.children.length);
```

But how can I get count of descendant of that node?

Do I need to use recurrence?

Any help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

This is with recursion.

```js
function getCount(parent) {
  var count = 0;

  if (Array.isArray(parent.children)) {
    count += parent.children.length;
    parent.children.forEach(function(child) {
      if (Array.isArray(child.children)) {
        count += getCount(child);
      }
    });
  }

  return count;
}

var d = {
  children: [
    1,
    {
      children: [
        1,
        2
      ]
    },
    2,
    3
  ]
};

console.log(getCount(d));
```

Comment: yours is not calculating parent if it has children. if A have children B, C and B have D, E then the descendants count of A should be 4. but yours should output 3, ( C, D, E)

Comment: You need to use it like this: `getCount(parent)` *not* like this `getCount(parent.children)`. With your example, you should call `getCount(d)`.